# Ionic - E/Capacitor: Unable to open asset URL

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic-vue

I can't load any image from external url in real device. I am always getting the following error:

[image]

This is my `capacitor.config.json`

```json
{
  ...,
  server: {
    cleartext: true,
    hostname: "rootsmenu.com",
    allowNavigation: [
      'localhost',
      'rootsmenu.com'
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I edited `capacitor.config.ts` with following configs and it worked! Also, I was editig the wrong file `android/app/src/main/assets/capacitor.config.json`. Because it was replaced with `capacitor.config.ts` content each time I ran `npx cap sync android`

**capacitor.config.ts**

```json
{
  ...
  "android": {
    "allowMixedContent": true
  },
  "server": {
    "cleartext": true,
    "hostname": "localhost"
  }
}
```

Comment: Sir I have tried above solution but my changes not showing after build can you let me know why changes not showing?

Comment: According to the [official documentation](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/config#schema) this should not be used in production, because its a security risk.

Comment: @Gereon99 documents are not telling how to include external resources

Comment: There's also an older reference to `allowMixedContent` in [Capacitor v2 docs](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v2/config): "On Android, if you are loading the app from a remote/testing server from https protocol, you need to enable mixed content mode to allow the WebView to load files from different schemes such as `capacitor-content://` or `capacitor-file://`".