# (Cordova/Capacitor) Download a file from its app?

Tags: android, cordova, download, filesystems, capacitor

**Goal :** My application creates a zip. User downloads it to their device.

**Problem :** It works perfectly with Electron and Browser, but with Android it doesn't work

### Try 1 window.showSaveFilePicker()

```
      const fileHandle = await window.showSaveFilePicker({suggestedName: 'package.zip'});
      const writable = await fileHandle.createWritable();
      await writable.write(blob);
      await writable.close();
```

Opens a window to save the file. Works on **Browser** and **Windows application**.
On **Android**, nothing happens.

### Try 2 Download Link

```
      const downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href =  downloadUrl; 
      link.target= '_blank';
      link.download = 'package.zip';
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
```

Opens a window to save the file. Works with **Browser** and **Windows application**.
With **Android**, none. AndroidStudio Log : E/Capacitor: Unable to open asset URL

### Try 3 Download Link with local file (Just to check)

```
<a href="/assets/imgs/pack.zip" download>DOWNLOAD</a>
```

Works with **Browser** and **Windows application**.
With **Android**, nothing, same error.

### Try 4 Alternative

```
const path = `${directory}/${name}`;
const blob = new Blob([file], {type: file.type});
const data = await this.blobToBase64(blob);
await Filesystem.writeFile({path, data, directory: Directory.Documents, encoding: Encoding.UTF8});
```

Use FileSystem (Directory.Documents) to save to user's device. I want to avoid, it's not user friendly and Doesn't work because the files are transformed to base64 to be used by the Android Filesystem API.
They are unusable. :/

### Additional info

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER"/>
```

**package.json**

```
"@capacitor/android": "^3.6.0",
"@capacitor/core": "^3.6.0",
"@capacitor/filesystem": "^1.1.0",
```

Comment: Are you using a framework maybe ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70657943/ionic-e-capacitor-unable-to-open-asset-url

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work with FileSharer plugin.

In my implementation, I retrieved the file through an HTTP request, but FileSharer also supports sharing files from a base64 source.

What it does is open a sharing popup that allows the user to save the file on filesystem or share it with other applications.

["@byteowls/capacitor-filesharer": "^4.0.0"](https://github.com/moberwasserlechner/capacitor-filesharer)

Here is my implementation:

```js
openFile(params: { res: any; filename: string}) {
    const file = new Blob([params.res], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});
    if (!window.hasOwnProperty('cordova')) {
      // Web implementation
    } else {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = () => {
          const dataUrl: any = reader?.result;
          if (dataUrl) {
            const base64 = dataUrl.split(',')[1];
            FileSharer.share({
              filename: params.filename,
              base64Data:   base64,
              contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
            });
          }

      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  }
```